# Showing that this intersection is an open set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be two disjoint and connected subsets of some metric space.
If $M \subset A\cup B$ is open in $A \cup B$, show that $A \cap M $ is open in $A$. I know that this can be done with the subset topology but I want to do this only with the metric space definition of open sets. I know that for $M$ I can write $\forall x \in M, \exists \epsilon>0: B_\epsilon(x)\subset M$, but now I'm stuck at trying to show the same for $A\cap M$.

Comment: $\forall x \in M, \exists \epsilon>0: B_\epsilon(x)\subset M$ is the definition for "$M$ open in the whole metric space", not for "$M$ is open in $A\cup B$...

Comment: We have $B_{\epsilon}(x) \cap A\subseteq A\cap M$, for any $x\in A\cap M$, showing $A\cap M$ is open in the subset topology.

Comment: @Momo: Could you please elaborate? How would the definition for $M$ open in $A\cup B$ be?

Comment: @Keio203 $\forall x \in M, \exists \epsilon>0: B_\epsilon(x)\cap(A\cup B)\subset M$. As counterexample to your definition, if $A\cup B=[0,\infty)$ and $M=[0,1)$, M is open in $A\cup B$, but no ball centered in $0$ is subset of $M$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$M \subset A\cup B$ is open in $A \cup B$, therefore $\forall x \in M, \exists \epsilon>0: B_\epsilon(x)\cap(A\cup B)\subset M$

If, in addition. if $x\in A$, then (since $A\cap B=\emptyset)$:

$
\begin{aligned}
M\cap A\supset (B_\epsilon(x)\cap(A\cup B))\cap A=(B_\epsilon(x)\cap A\cap A)\cup (B_\epsilon(x)\cap B\cap A) = (B_\epsilon(x)\cap A)\cup \emptyset=B_\epsilon(x)\cap A
\end{aligned}
$

Which means that $M\cap A$ is open in A.